# Flask Webserver on Amazon Linux 2 - This site can’t be reached on browser

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2

I have started a Flask Webserver on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instances

```
(venv) [ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-63 microblog]$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'microblog.py'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

When i try to access the Web either via the below Public V4 DNS or Public V4 IP i get "Site cannot be reached"

- http://34.228.161.61:5000
- http://34.228.161.61:5000/index
- https://ec2-34-228-161-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000
- https://ec2-34-228-161-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000/index

I have successfully launched an Apache Web Server into the same EC2 & VPC instances and have no issues.

Also running curl from the same server i launched flask returns the contents

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-63 ~]$ curl http://localhost:7999
Hello, World![ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-63 ~]$
```

(tried a range of other ports also)

Any clues on what to do to get it working from my Chrome/Safari browser?

Tried so far

- Ensured EC2 was talking to the web
- Ensured VPC had route to the public internet
- Ensured other webservers could be launched successfully from the same EC2 instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be your application is not allowed for the outside world (0.0.0.0). Please check the running port in your system. You can use the below command to check:

> **sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN**

[image]

check if  0.0.0.0: in your case, 0.0.0.0:5000 is showing in output or not.

Then try to run with below command:

> flask run --host=0.0.0.0

Let me know, if that works. #Cloudkaramchari

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      322/python3

Comment: use this command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0

Comment: This has worked: Now on the ec2 commandline i get a message saying "running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)"......thank you very much